# How to prevent Scrapy from URL encoding request URLs

Tags: python, url, scrapy, url-encoding, web-crawler

I would like Scrapy to not URL encode my Requests. I see that scrapy.http.Request is importing scrapy.utils.url which imports w3lib.url which contains the variable _ALWAYS_SAFE_BYTES. I just need to add a set of characters to _ALWAYS_SAFE_BYTES but I am not sure how to do that from within my spider class.

scrapy.http.Request relevant line:

```
fp.update(canonicalize_url(request.url))
```

canonicalize_url is from scrapy.utils.url, relevant line in scrapy.utils.url:

```
path = safe_url_string(_unquotepath(path)) or '/'
```

safe_url_string() is from w3lib.url, relevant lines in w3lib.url:

```
_ALWAYS_SAFE_BYTES = (b'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_.-')
```

within w3lib.url.safe_url_string():

```
_safe_chars = _ALWAYS_SAFE_BYTES + b'%' + _reserved + _unreserved_marks
return moves.urllib.parse.quote(s, _safe_chars)
```

Comment: I'm facing this problem because a web server accepts comma only unencoded, but Scrapy translates it in links into %2C.

Comment: I needed to quickly work around the problem, so I added self._url = self._url.replace('%2C', ',') into Request._set_url(). Removing the safe_url_string(url) call from the same function didn't help.

Comment: Any solution? ... I need it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to not to encode `[` and `]` and I did this.

When creating a `Request` object scrapy applies some url encoding methods. To revert these you can utilize a custom middleware and change the url to your needs.

You could use a `Downloader Middleware` like this:

```
class MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request._url = request.url.replace("%5B", "[", 2)
        request._url = request.url.replace("%5D", "]", 2)
```

Don't forget to "activate" the middleware in `settings.py` like so:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'so.middlewares.MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware': 900,
}
```

My project is named `so` and in the folder there is a file `middlewares.py`. You need to adjust those to your environment.

Credit goes to: [Frank Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42492045/4094231)