# How can I get an output in UTF-8 encoded unicode from Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

Bear with me. I'm writing every detail because so many parts of the toolchain do not handle Unicode gracefully and it's not clear what is failing.

**PRELUDE**

We first set up and use a recent Scrapy.

```
source ~/.scrapy_1.1.2/bin/activate
```

Since the terminal's default is ascii, not unicode, we set:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Also since by default Python uses ascii, we modify the encoding:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING="utf_8"
```

Now we're ready to start a Scrapy project.

```
scrapy startproject myproject
cd myproject
scrapy genspider dorf PLACEHOLDER
```

We're told we now have a spider.

```
Created spider 'dorf' using template 'basic' in module:
  myproject.spiders.dorf
```

We modify `myproject/items.py` to be:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class MyprojectItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
```

**ATTEMPT 1**

Now we write the [spider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39570495/704972), relying on `urllib.unquote`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import urllib
from myproject.items import MyprojectItem

class DorfSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dorf"
    allowed_domains = [u'http://en.sistercity.info/']
    start_urls = (
        u'http://en.sistercity.info/sister-cities/Düsseldorf.html',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        item = MyprojectItem()
        item['title'] = urllib.unquote(
            response.xpath('//title').extract_first().encode('ascii')
        ).decode('utf8')
        return item
```

And finally we use a [custom item exporter](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scrapy-users/rJcfSFVZ3O4) (from all the way back in Oct 2011)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
from scrapy.exporters import BaseItemExporter

class UnicodeJsonLinesItemExporter(BaseItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, file, **kwargs):
        self._configure(kwargs)
        self.file = file
        self.encoder = json.JSONEncoder(ensure_ascii=False, **kwargs)

    def export_item(self, item):
        itemdict = dict(self._get_serialized_fields(item))
        self.file.write(self.encoder.encode(itemdict) + '\n')
```

and add

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'json': 'myproject.exporters.UnicodeJsonLinesItemExporter',
}
```

to `myproject/settings.py`.

Now we run

```
~/myproject> scrapy crawl dorf -o dorf.json -t json
```

we get

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 25: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**ATTEMPT 2**

Another solution (the candidate solution for Scrapy 1.2?) is to use the spider

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from myproject.items import MyprojectItem

class DorfSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dorf"
    allowed_domains = [u'http://en.sistercity.info/']
    start_urls = (
        u'http://en.sistercity.info/sister-cities/Düsseldorf.html',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        item = MyprojectItem()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//title')[0].extract()
        return item
```

and the [custom item exporter](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1963#issuecomment-215797219)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.exporters import JsonItemExporter

class Utf8JsonItemExporter(JsonItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, file, **kwargs):
        super(Utf8JsonItemExporter, self).__init__(
            file, ensure_ascii=False, **kwargs)
```

with

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'json': 'myproject.exporters.Utf8JsonItemExporter',
}
```

in `myproject/settings.py`.

We get the following JSON file.

```
[
{"title": "<title>Sister cities of D\u00fcsseldorf \u2014 sistercity.info</title>"}
]
```

The Unicode is not UTF-8 encoded. Although this is a trivial problem for a couple of characters, it becomes a serious issue if the entire output is in a foreign language.

How can I get an output in UTF-8 unicode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try this on your **Attempt 1** and let me know if it works (I've test it without setting all those env. variables)

```
def to_write(uni_str):
    return urllib.unquote(uni_str.encode('utf8')).decode('utf8')


class CitiesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "cities"
    allowed_domains = ["sitercity.info"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://en.sistercity.info/sister-cities/Düsseldorf.html',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        for i in range(2):
            item = SimpleItem()
            item['title'] = to_write(response.xpath('//title').extract_first())
            item['url'] = to_write(response.url)
            yield item
```

the `range(2)` is for testing the json exporter, to get a list of dicts you can do this instead:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import JsonItemExporter
from scrapy.utils.serialize import ScrapyJSONEncoder

class UnicodeJsonLinesItemExporter(JsonItemExporter):
    def __init__(self, file, **kwargs):
        self._configure(kwargs, dont_fail=True)
        self.file = file
        self.encoder = ScrapyJSONEncoder(ensure_ascii=False, **kwargs)
        self.first_item = True
```

Answer (score 19):

In Scrapy 1.2+ there is a [FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-export-encoding) option. When `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = "utf-8"` escaping of non-ascii symbols in JSON output is turned off.

Comment: how to add FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING in scrapy spider

Comment: Put it into settings.py file