# Encode Scrapy output to allow French letters

Tags: python, encoding, scrapy

I have a Scrapy script that parses from a french site. I use the command `scrapy runspider test.py -o test2.csv` to get output.  The output is not displaying non-english letters such as **"Premium Sécurité de tuyau."** How can I modify settings or `item` dictionary values encoding to display the name as shown.  Visit [amazon french](https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B0013HOAKK) for an example of French characters that I must parse.

If I use:

`response.xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"]/text()').extract_first().strip().encode("utf-8").decode("ascii","ignore")`

I get "Gardena 8169-30 Premium SÃ©curitÃ© de tuyau d'arrosage 19 mm (1,9 cm (0,75"))"

I checked this [scrapy encoding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582409/how-can-i-get-an-output-in-utf-8-encoded-unicode-from-scrapy) but I think it is for python2 (I use python3). Basically, what I am looking for is getting the name as it displayed on the site.

Comment: Are you checking output CSV file or do you see above encoding issue in Excel (or similar) after import?

Comment: @gangabass I am seeing in Excel

Answer (score 1):

You need to import from CSV manually in Excel and select UTF-8 encoding.

[Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically)

Comment: `response.xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"]/text()').extract_first().strip().encode("utf-8")` like this, then I import manually ?

Comment: You don't need to use `.encode('utf-8")`. Scrapy save output as UTF-8 by default. It's Excel issue.