# Force Python Scrapy not to encode URL

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

There are some URLs with `[]` in it like

```
http://www.website.com/CN.html?value_ids[]=33&value_ids[]=5007
```

But when I try scraping this URL with Scrapy, it makes Request to this URL

```
http://www.website.com/CN.html?value_ids%5B%5D=33&value_ids%5B%5D=5007
```

How can I force scrapy to not to urlenccode my URLs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a `Request` object scrapy applies some url encoding methods. To revert these you can utilize a custom middleware and change the url to your needs.

You could use a `Downloader Middleware` like this:

```
class MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request._url = request.url.replace("%5B", "[", 2)
        request._url = request.url.replace("%5D", "]", 2)
```

Don't forget to "activate" the middleware in `settings.py` like so:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'so.middlewares.MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware': 900,
}
```

My project is named `so` and in the folder there is a file `middlewares.py`. You need to adjust those to your environment.

Comment: Awesome, never thought about that